# How to integrate Quickbooks desktop Application with a PHP(web app)?

Tags: php, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, qbxml

In my application, i want to use php to integrate QuickBooks by PHP. So From a web server(with PHP), I want to call QuickBooks Desktop version App to push data and retrieve data.

I am stuck here. I do not know where to start? Someone asked me to start with webconnector. I wonder like other webservices have a URL, we need to push the data to that url and they will do the rest. Is this the same? Or any other process I need to follw?

So Please please can any one there to help me out? I want to to know the full process and if any sample code available for the same in php.

Requirement:
1. My app is in Filemaker.
2. FIlemaker send the data to PHP file.
2. Then PHP file will send the data(in QBXML format) to Quickbooks Desktop Application.

Please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a [PHP QuickBooks Library](https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php) which does exactly what you want to do.

You should follow the [QuickBooks PHP Web Connector quick-start guide](http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/PHP_DevKit_for_QuickBooks_-_Quick-Start) to get started. You'll want to architect your application so that your PHP script can receive the data, store it temporarily in a database (MySQL, etc.) and then the Web Connector can pick up the data destined for QuickBooks from there.

The Web Connector is a little different than a standard web service in that it works in a sort of backwards manner - the Web Connector will call out to *your PHP web service* vs. you calling out to it.

There's a [overview of how the Web Connector works over here](http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_web_connector).

You should refer to this script (as the quick-start guide does above):

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/tree/master/docs/example_app_web_connector

You'll end up writing functions to generate qbXML requests that look something like this:

```
<?php

/**
 * Example Web Connector application
 * 
 * This is a very simple application that allows someone to enter a customer 
 * name into a web form, and then adds the customer to QuickBooks.
 * 
 * @author Keith Palmer <keith@consolibyte.com>
 * 
 * @package QuickBooks
 * @subpackage Documentation
 */

/**
 * Generate a qbXML response to add a particular customer to QuickBooks
 */
function _quickbooks_customer_add_request($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale)
{
        // Grab the data from our MySQL database
        $arr = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my_customer_table WHERE id = " . (int) $ID));

        $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                <?qbxml version="2.0"?>
                <QBXML>
                        <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
                                <CustomerAddRq requestID="' . $requestID . '">
                                        <CustomerAdd>
                                                <Name>' . $arr['name'] . '</Name>
                                                <CompanyName>' . $arr['name'] . '</CompanyName>
                                                <FirstName>' . $arr['fname'] . '</FirstName>
                                                <LastName>' . $arr['lname'] . '</LastName>
                                        </CustomerAdd>
                                </CustomerAddRq>
                        </QBXMLMsgsRq>
                </QBXML>';

        return $xml;
}
```

Comment: Your library is way too outdated. No support for PDO, overcomplicated structure, outdated methods. When to expect updated version?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this one - https://github.com/jewelhuq/quickbook-desktop-connection-php.
Last checked on 2021. Tried to use consolibyte but it did not worked. So made a new library.

Answer (score -2):

Intuit also has a PHP SDK for v3 of the QuickBooks API.
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits

regards
Jarred

Comment: This question is asking about desktop php api not the quickbook online.