# Quickbooks desktop app with PHP Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, quickbooks

I have to dump all the timesheet information to QuickBooks desktop application. Currently I am using PHP 7.x and Laravel 5.6.

So while I was looking for solution, I come across many links and struck on the links below. By seeing the below links what I understand is that I need to have a web connector in order to communicate with QB desktop. In local server, I have installed the web connector and trying to add an application to QB desktop software which was giving the error.

So I want to know where was my mistake and I cannot able to identify myself.

If there is any alternatives also I can check on them. Please suggest

http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/PHP_DevKit_for_QuickBooks_-_Quick-Start

https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php

[How to integrate Quickbooks desktop Application with a PHP(web app)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19558928/how-to-integrate-quickbooks-desktop-application-with-a-phpweb-app)

I have installed an QB trail version trying to add an application getting below error

```
20181106.17:43:36 UTC   : QWCReader.ParseQWC() : Contents of QWC file: -
<QBWCXML>
  <AppName>My QuickBooks SOAP Server</AppName>
  <AppID></AppID>
  <AppURL>http://127.0.0.1/quickbooks/docs/web_connector/qb_web_connector.php</AppURL>
  <AppDescription>TimeshEASY + QuickBooks</AppDescription>
  <AppSupport>http://127.0.0.1</AppSupport>
  <UserName>quickbooks</UserName>
  <OwnerID>{766f3bc7-1539-3624-a57e-298edc982f5c}</OwnerID>
  <FileID>{d886252c-10d8-e515-25f7-e1d8097c1ebd}</FileID>
  <QBType>QBFS</QBType>
  <Notify>false</Notify>
  <Scheduler>
    <RunEveryNMinutes>60</RunEveryNMinutes>
  </Scheduler>
  <IsReadOnly>false</IsReadOnly>
</QBWCXML>
20181106.17:43:36 UTC   : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.ReadQWC(QWCReader QWC) : Parsing application configuration xml file to load its content to variables
20181106.17:43:37 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.createRegKey() : Error creating registry key for appName = <>
20181106.17:43:37 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.createRegKey() : Reason: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: name
20181106.17:43:37 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.SerializeToRegistry() : Error saving My QuickBooks SOAP Server to Registry: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
20181106.17:43:37 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ConnectToQB() : Connecting to QuickBooks...
20181106.17:43:37 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ConnectToQB() : Error connecting to QuickBooks. Error message received from QuickBooks was <If the QuickBooks company data file is not open, a call to the "BeginSession" method must include the name of the data file.>.
20181106.17:43:37 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.AddToQuickBooks() : QBWC1039: There was a problem adding the application. Check QWCLog.txt for details.
<Error connecting to QuickBooks. Error message received from QuickBooks was <If the QuickBooks company data file is not open, a call to the "BeginSession" method must include the name of the data file.>.>
   at QBWebConnector.WebService.AddToQuickBooks()
20181106.17:43:46 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.DisconnectFromQB() : QBWC1015: Error closing connection to QuickBooks.
Reason: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: g
```

Kindly help me on this thank you

Comment: Just a note that no one is going to visit those links, which will be dead in an internet moment anyway. If there is anything in those links that needs to be part of the question, just [edit] it and put it in the text. AS for the problem you report, what debugging and research step shave you taken? The error message refers to logs and mentions null values and an unopened file. Have you researched this?

Comment: @jdv the printed XML i am parsing(with .QWC extension), it didn't have null value while parsing you can see in the log also

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: @mypetlion yes I passed .QWC file to QB software and it is giving an error

Comment: Can you please detail the workflow that led to the error?

Comment: @mypetlion can you help me on this in any manner. Just reference or anything I could go with.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and tell us as clearly as you can: 1. what you are trying to do; 2. what you tried; 3. what results you got. Comments are not for adding information to a question.

Comment: Wait, are you running code you wrote yourself, or some utility found on the internet? If you wrote this code, show a [mcve]. If you did not, then this question is probably off-topic and may belong on another SE site.

Comment: @mypetlion I have updated my question so hope it is better now

Comment: @jdv found some sample from the Quickbooks in the internet I am trying to use it

Comment: Show your [mcve].

Comment: Post your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the logs, QuickBooks is saying:

`If the QuickBooks company data file is not open, a call to the "BeginSession" method must include the name of the data file.`

What this means it that QuickBooks doesn't think your data file is open.

- Close the Web Connector (literally choose `File > Exit` to make sure it exists, not just hides in the tray)
- Open QuickBooks
- Log in to your QuickBooks company file as `Admin`
- Choose `File > Update Web Services` from the menu, to open the Web Connector
- Re-add your `.QWC` file to the Web Connector

You must have the QuickBooks company data file open to get connected.

Most importantly, *post your code* and *post your logs from the Web Connector* if you continue to have problems. We can't help you if we can't see what you're doing.